# Права доступа на файл

Tags: python, nginx, права

На сервере python + nginx.

Python запущен от user, nginx от www-data.

На сайте есть возможность загрузить фото, кодом это изображение нарезается, и сохраняется в нужную папку. при этом оригинал сохраняется с правами 770, а новая нарезка с правами 660.
Но через сайт нельзя просмотреть ни одну из них.
Если я только в ручную меняю права на 755, тогда через сайт становятся доступны эти картинки.
Я пробовал в /etc/group добавить пользователя www-data в группу к user, надеясь что тем самым и nginx и python будут иметь общую группу, и у них будет доступ к файлам, но я ошибся.

Что я делаю не верно, от кого нужно что запускать, или какие-то настройки на сервере сделать, или еще что? Есть вариант в коде в ручную назначать права сохраняемым файлам, но ИМХО это криво, думаю должен быть выход на уровне настройки сервера.

Спасибо за внимание.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Установите SGID-флаг на директориях, доступных через web. Что-то в таком духе:

```
chgrp -R www-data /var/www
find /var/www -type d -exec chmod g+s '{}' \;
```

Тогда создаваемые в этих директориях файлы будут принадлежать группе www-data.

Права, с которыми создается файл, по возможности, задавайте явно в коде (не забывая, что они будут ограничены [umask](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask) процесса).

Более гибким вариантом (если таковой требуется, если не нужно — проще обойтись SGID-битом), при условии поддержки файловой системой POSIX Access Control Lists (для ext3/ext4 — флаг `acl` при монтировании) может быть задание прав с использованием [`setfacl`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Access_Control_Lists_(%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9)#.D0.A3.D1.81.D1.82.D0.B0.D0.BD.D0.BE.D0.B2.D0.BA.D0.B0_.D0.BF.D1.80.D0.B0.D0.B2_ACL).

Comment: Не помогло выставлением SGID-флаг.  

Значит буду программно назначать права.  
Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Странно. Сделайте `ls -la` в директории с загруженными файлами (которые не открываются) и покажите, пожалуйста, кусочек вывода.

Comment: Красным выделены те что я в ручную поменял на 755, а вот зеленым и розовым это фото созданные кодом.  
http://clip2net.com/s/2veVH

Comment: @trec: Ну так все файлы, судя по дате, загружены еще того, как была проведена смена прав на директорию (17:21). Сделайте `chgrp www-data *`, чтобы сменить им группу. А вот уже новые файлы должны появляться с правильной группой уже самостоятельно.

За одним исключением — если Вы файлы при загрузке сначала создаете где-нибудь, скажем, в `/tmp`, а потом перемещаете в этот каталог — вот в этом случае группа **не** поменяется (и так и будет `kard`). SGID надо ставить у того места, где файлы создаются.

Comment: Алсо, если не можете разобраться — добавьте пользователя `www-data` в группу `kard`, а не `user`, и перезапустите веб-сервер (это важно, иначе добавление в группу не будут замечено — определение списка групп происходит именно при запуске процесса). Но это костыльное решение, нехорошо как-то давать `www-data` такие широкие полномочия.

Comment: Да, действительно, у меня файлы создаются в /tmp, не думал что это важно. Назначил этому каталогу группу www-data, потом SGID поставил на этот каталог, ничего не изменилось (перезапускал сервер). В общем помогло одно, добавление пользователя www-data в группу kard. начали отображаться и старые фотки, и новозагруженные.  
Жаль что это костыльное решение, как Вы говорите, только сработало, хотелось все по правильному сделать. Но пусть хотя бы так работает, ибо в коде расставлять права ну никак не хотелось, хотя опять же, если это будет угрожать безопасности, то буду делать в коде.  
Спасибо Вам

Answer (score 2):

Создайте файл от пользователя user, если права будут 660, то смотрите параметр umask (по дефолту 0022, в вашем случае он 117). Если же права будут отличные то скажите разработчикам что бы настроили/использовали os.umask.

Comment: Создал файл, файл с правами 0664 создался.  Я и есть разработчик, но не понял что значит настроили/использовали os.umask?

Comment: Ну смотрите, после обработки вашим кодом изображения на файловой системе создаются в виде файлов с владельцем user, и правами 660, последний ноль означает, что "остальные" не могут ни читать не писать и не исполнять данный файл, nginx от пользователя www-data относится к таким пользователям "остальным", в вашем случае. Так вот, когда вы в коде создаете файл, используйте модуль os.umask(), и задавайте нужную маску для вновь создаваемых файлов.

Comment: Добавил www-data в группу к пользователю user, всё заработало. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй скриптом менять права при обрезке , 751 права выставь.
Увы не помню какая функция за это отвечает. поищи в модуле OS

Comment: Делал так для одного проекта, но все же интересно, есть ли возможность настроить это на самом сервере, расставив правильно права.

Answer (score 0):

Если загрузка файлов идёт через движок сайта, то права определяются настройками движка. Там и искать надо!